# Read specific content from different files in an array

Tags: php, file

I have got different files in one directory. Each file consists the string "name_service  ".
The values are different. In my PHP Script I need to read the values in one array.

I found the PHP-function "file()" to read the filecontent to an array, but this seem only to work if the php-file and the files to read are in the same directory.

I need a function to read the content of a file to an array which is not in the same directory as the PHP-files.

Comment: It all depends on the format of the file. You can use `file_get_contents` to read an entire file into a string and then parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will work for any file in filesystem:

```
$data = file('directory/file.txt');
```

You should only use here correct file path.

Directory may be relative to current path and in current path (as above), or relative to current path but in other directory for example `../directory/file.txt` or it can be absolute path: `/usr/etc/file.txt`